# How to use ffmpeg frei0r filter with mixer2 plugins

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using [frei0r-20121203-git-f4bac51-filters-win64.7z](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=312&sid=16deb3c708d4d0f753fc961b25baa6d9&start=10#p3467) and zeranoe ffmpeg, then set PATH.
twolay0r plugin is fine, but value plugin is error.

```
set FREI0R_PATH=frei0r-20121203-git-f4bac51-filters-win64
```

fine

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i testsrc -vf frei0r=twolay0r
```

error

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i testsrc -vf frei0r=value
```

```
ffplay version N-72276-gf99fed7 Copyright (c) 2003-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 39.101 / 56. 39.101
  libavformat    56. 33.101 / 56. 33.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'testsrc':   0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 320x240 [SAR 1:1
 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 000000000311ec80] Invalid type 'mixer2' for this plugin
Error initializing filter 'frei0r' with args 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use mixer2 or mixer3 plugins with FFmpeg, as that support is missing in code.